# How to use relationships in controllers with laravel for retrieving data?

Tags: laravel

I have the model which creates a one to many relationship between user and comment:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

How can I use the model within controller by using DB to get use of the model functionality(relationship)?

Instead of using the routes:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
$Comments = App\Comment::all();
return view('Commentss', ['Comments' => $Comments]);
});
```

I want to use the controller but doesn't work?

```
$Comments = DB::table('comments')->get(); (is there a way to use DB with model)

Or 

use App\Comment;
$Comments = App\Comment::all(); (this says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Comment' not found)
```

So that in the end I can retrieve the data in view by:

```
<p>{{$Comment->user->whatever}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
$Comments = \App\Comment::all();
```

Or better add `use App\Comment;` at the top of the controller and then:

```
$Comments = Comment::all();
```